# Change Image Slider Caption to Static

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a jquery slider called pgwslidemaster.i want to show the slider caption in a div that can to change it and add a tag to that. but the problem is i can't see the slider caption it is define with alt in image but i don't want it. is there any way to change caption of image from Alt to a separate tag?
here is my Snippet :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.pgwSlideshow').pgwSlideshow({
      autoSlide: true
    });
});
```

```css
.slides {
  width: 700px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.slides ul {
  list-style: inside none disc;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src='https://cdn.rawgit.com/Pagawa/PgwSlideshow/master/pgwslideshow.min.js'></script>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdn.rawgit.com/Pagawa/PgwSlideshow/master/pgwslideshow.min.css'>

</head>

<body>


<div class="slides">
    <ul class="pgwSlideshow">
                <li><img src="http://static.pgwjs.com/img/pg/slideshow/san-francisco.jpg" alt="San Francisco, USA" data-description="Golden Gate Bridge"></li>
        <li><img src="http://static.pgwjs.com/img/pg/slideshow/rio.jpg" alt="Rio de Janeiro, Brazil"></li>
        <li><img src="http://static.pgwjs.com/img/pg/slideshow/london_mini.jpg" alt="" data-large-src="http://static.pgwjs.com/img/pg/slideshow/london.jpg"></li>
        <li><img src="http://static.pgwjs.com/img/pg/slideshow/new-york.jpg" alt=""></li>
        <li><img src="http://static.pgwjs.com/img/pg/slideshow/new-delhi.jpg" alt=""></li>
        <li><img src="http://static.pgwjs.com/img/pg/slideshow/paris.jpg" alt=""></li>
        <li><img src="http://static.pgwjs.com/img/pg/slideshow/sydney.jpg" alt=""></li>
        <li><img src="http://static.pgwjs.com/img/pg/slideshow/tokyo.jpg" alt=""></li>
        <li><img src="http://static.pgwjs.com/img/pg/slideshow/honk-kong.jpg" alt=""></li>
        <li><img src="http://static.pgwjs.com/img/pg/slideshow/dakar.jpg" alt=""></li>
        <li><img src="http://static.pgwjs.com/img/pg/slideshow/toronto.jpg" alt=""></li>
        <li><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monaco" target="_blank"><img src="http://static.pgwjs.com/img/pg/slideshow/monaco.jpg" alt="Monaco"></a></li>
            </ul>
</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: Please rephrase you question. Its unclear to me.

Comment: i want to show my image's caption in a div .

Comment: Where is that `div`?

Comment: there is not any div. is there a way to create a div then show the caption of each image on it?instead of alt attribute?

Answer (score 0):

What exactly you have to do by moving caption into some div ? 
Do you want to add some CSS to it?
if that is the case then you can do it by applying css to caption span class .ps-caption.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.pgwSlideshow').pgwSlideshow({
      autoSlide: true
    });
});
```

```css
.slides {
  width: 700px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.slides ul {
  list-style: inside none disc;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.pgwSlideshow .ps-caption { /* Override code here*/
  background: rgba(333,0,0,0.5) !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src='https://cdn.rawgit.com/Pagawa/PgwSlideshow/master/pgwslideshow.min.js'></script>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdn.rawgit.com/Pagawa/PgwSlideshow/master/pgwslideshow.min.css'>

</head>

<body>


<div class="slides">
    <ul class="pgwSlideshow">
                <li><img src="http://static.pgwjs.com/img/pg/slideshow/san-francisco.jpg" alt="San Francisco, USA" data-description="Golden Gate Bridge"></li>
        <li><img src="http://static.pgwjs.com/img/pg/slideshow/rio.jpg" alt="Rio de Janeiro, Brazil"></li>
        <li><img src="http://static.pgwjs.com/img/pg/slideshow/london_mini.jpg" alt="" data-large-src="http://static.pgwjs.com/img/pg/slideshow/london.jpg"></li>
        <li><img src="http://static.pgwjs.com/img/pg/slideshow/new-york.jpg" alt=""></li>
        <li><img src="http://static.pgwjs.com/img/pg/slideshow/new-delhi.jpg" alt=""></li>
        <li><img src="http://static.pgwjs.com/img/pg/slideshow/paris.jpg" alt=""></li>
        <li><img src="http://static.pgwjs.com/img/pg/slideshow/sydney.jpg" alt=""></li>
        <li><img src="http://static.pgwjs.com/img/pg/slideshow/tokyo.jpg" alt=""></li>
        <li><img src="http://static.pgwjs.com/img/pg/slideshow/honk-kong.jpg" alt=""></li>
        <li><img src="http://static.pgwjs.com/img/pg/slideshow/dakar.jpg" alt=""></li>
        <li><img src="http://static.pgwjs.com/img/pg/slideshow/toronto.jpg" alt=""></li>
        <li><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monaco" target="_blank"><img src="http://static.pgwjs.com/img/pg/slideshow/monaco.jpg" alt="Monaco"></a></li>
            </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: it's not for Css. i want to put caption in < a href=""></a> tag . furture more put some icon in the caption.

Comment: in that case you can use afterSlide option available in pgwSlideshow and write a code to display custom elements in caption.

Comment: Hi @inaz is this working for you ? I have also posted another answer with implementation of same concept.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will work for you.
I have added id for each slide and added data attribute with link and text you want in caption which is then appended in caption span with hyperlink on afterSlide event.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.pgwSlideshow').pgwSlideshow({
      autoSlide: true,
afterSlide: function(id) { 
       $('.pgwSlideshow .ps-caption').html("<a href='"+ $('#slide-'+id).attr('data-href') +"'>"+ $('#slide-'+id).attr('data-text')+"</a>").show();
      }
    });
});
```

```css
.slides {
  width: 700px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.slides ul {
  list-style: inside none disc;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.pgwSlideshow .ps-caption { /* Override code here*/
  background: rgba(333,0,0,0.5) !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src='https://cdn.rawgit.com/Pagawa/PgwSlideshow/master/pgwslideshow.min.js'></script>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdn.rawgit.com/Pagawa/PgwSlideshow/master/pgwslideshow.min.css'>

</head>

<body>


<div class="slides">
    <ul class="pgwSlideshow">
        <li><img src="http://static.pgwjs.com/img/pg/slideshow/san-francisco.jpg" id='slide-1' data-text="Golden Gate Bridge" data-href='http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monaco'></li>
        <li><img src="http://static.pgwjs.com/img/pg/slideshow/rio.jpg" id='slide-2' data-text="Rio" data-href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monaco"></li>
        <li><img src="http://static.pgwjs.com/img/pg/slideshow/london_mini.jpg" data-text="london" id='slide-3' data-href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monaco" data-large-src="http://static.pgwjs.com/img/pg/slideshow/london.jpg"></li>
        <li><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monaco" target="_blank"><img src="http://static.pgwjs.com/img/pg/slideshow/monaco.jpg" data-text="Monaco" id='slide-4' data-href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monaco"></a></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```